# $φ(z)=\int_{γ_z}^{}\frac{f'}{f}$ show that $e^φ=f$ in $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be an open, simple connected set, a point $z_0 \in D$ and the holomorphic function on $D$ with $f(z)\neq 0$ for every $z \in D$. We consider a $C^1$ curve $γ_z $ such that it connects $z_0$ to $z$.
Show that the integral $\int_{γ_z}^{}\frac{f'}{f}$ doesn't depend on the curve, but only from $z$.
$$φ(z)=\int_{γ_z}^{}\frac{f'(ζ)}{f(ζ)}dζ$$
show that $e^φ=f$ in $D$

---

Because $f$ is homomorphic in $D$ so its $f'$ as well and because $f\neq 0,\: \frac{f'}{f}$  is also homomorphic in a simple connected. So for every close path, Cauchy theorem gives us that the line integral (on the closed path) is zero. From the theorem of independence $\frac{f'}{f}$ has antiderivative, thus indeed $φ(z)$ doesn't depend on the curve, but from $z$.

Now consider $g(z)=e^{φ(z)}-f(z)$,

$g'=f'/f\cdot g \Rightarrow$ $(\frac{g}{f})'=c'\Rightarrow e^{φ(z)}-f(z)=cf(z ) \Rightarrow e^{φ(z)}=(c+1)f(z)$,  this is where I stuck, how do I show $c=0$

I also notice $φ(z_0)=0$, but I don't see how that gives me something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $\phi' = f'/f$. Now the “trick” is to consider the function $h(z) = e^{-\phi(z)} f(z)$. Then
$$
 h'(z) = e^{-\phi(z)} \left( f'(z) - \phi'(z) f(z)\right) = 0
$$
so that $h$ is constant. It follows that
$$
e^{-\phi(z)} f(z) = e^{-\phi(z_0)} f(z_0) = f(z_0)
$$
for all $z \in D$, i.e.
$$
 e^{\phi(z)} = f(z)/f(z_0) \, .
$$
If $z_0$ is chosen such that $f(z_0)=1$ then $e^\phi = f$, but that is not the case for arbitrary $z_0$.